# why does fibonacci suquence not working when added document.getElement?

Tags: javascript

I added document.getElementById on the firstNum and secondNum so that user can input the numbers but it doesnt seem to work.It shows undefined and the rest is NaN.

```
function fibonacci(){
let firstNum = document.getElementById('firstNums').val;
let secondNum = document.getElementById('secondNums').val;
let result = secondNum;

for(i=0; i < 9; i++) {
  document.write(result + '<br/>');
  
  result = firstNum + secondNum;// = 5
  firstNum = secondNum;//firstNum is 2 from the secondNum
  secondNum = result;//secondNum is 5 from the result and so on...
 }
}
```

Comment: Should you be getting the values from `.value` instead of `.val`?

Comment: The `val` property is always going to be `undefined`. Did you mean `value`? (Voting to close because the problem appears to be caused by a typo. The question would probably have benefited from an [mcve] in the form of a live demo though)

Comment: owww im used to jquery im sorry about that

Comment: But even in jQuery that wouldn't work -- it should be `val()` not `val`... More specifically `$('#firstNums').val()`

Comment: also to add numbers, the sum should be : `result = Number(firstNum) + Number(secondNum);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is what you need to get from the inputs and then because all inputs yield strings - the values need to be parsed into numbers.

The following uses the calculation from your snippet and then inserts them into a ul so that you can re-use the inputs.

```js
document.getElementById('calculate').addEventListener('click', fibonacci);

function fibonacci(){
  let firstNum = parseInt(document.getElementById('firstNums').value, 10);
  let secondNum = parseInt(document.getElementById('secondNums').value, 10);

  let result = secondNum;
  let resultStr = '';

  for(i=0; i < 9; i++) {
   resultStr += '<li>' + result + '</li>';
    result = firstNum + secondNum;
    firstNum = secondNum;
    secondNum = result;
   }
 document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultStr
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="firstNums" placeholder="first number"/>
<input type="text" id="secondNums" placeholder="second number" />
<button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
<hr/>
<ul id="result"></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked just by adding parseInt on it... btw what is the use of "10" beside the value?

Comment: The number is the radix and specifies the base number system that you are using  - https://davidwalsh.name/parseint-radix

Answer (score -1):

You should use the [`value`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp) property which sets or returns the value of the value attribute of a text field.

```
let firstNum = document.getElementById('firstNums').value;
let secondNum = document.getElementById('secondNums').value;
```

Comment: yes i did it im used in jquery but why does is not return to same result?

Comment: Use parseInt(string). See @gavgrif answer.